# Piping data following grouping by variables into a conditional ifelse statement

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, group-by

Vague example:
For every instance where var.w and var.x  is the same, remove the rows of data for when var.y is a smaller numerical value and var.z is zero.

More clarification:

- I want: for every instance where 'tree.id' and 'year' is the same, remove the data of the lesser 'week' value if 'pa' is zero
- Week is numeric, values of: 0.43, 1, 2, 3
- pa is a presence-absence variable (0/1)

I tried:

```
terminal.obs.fr %>% group_by(year, tree.id) %>% tally()
```

This shows me the data where duplicate rows exist.

I then attempted my above question by a one-liner which does not work:

```
B <- terminal.obs.fr %>% ifelse(group_by(year, tree.id)%>%tally() >1, "T","F")
```

Original data subseted using dput(droplevels(df[,])

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(44L, 47L, 47L, 49L, 9L, 65L, 
71L, 4L, 71L, 13L, 69L, 72L, 58L, 60L, 63L, 58L, 60L, 63L), .Label = c("2021-05-03", 
"2021-05-05", "2021-05-07", "2021-05-11", "2021-05-12", "2021-05-14", 
"2021-05-17", "2021-05-19", "2021-05-21", "2021-05-25", "2021-05-26", 
"2021-05-28", "2021-05-31", "2021-06-04", "2021-06-07", "2021-06-11", 
"2021-06-14", "2021-06-15", "2021-06-16", "2021-06-18", "2021-06-20", 
"2021-06-21", "2021-06-22", "2021-06-25", "2021-06-27", "2021-06-28", 
"2021-06-29", "2021-07-02", "2021-07-03", "2021-07-05", "2021-07-06", 
"2021-07-09", "2021-07-12", "2021-07-13", "2021-07-16", "2021-07-19", 
"2021-07-20", "2021-07-23", "2021-07-25", "2021-07-26", "2021-07-27", 
"2021-07-30", "2021-08-02", "2021-08-03", "2021-08-06", "2021-08-09", 
"2021-08-10", "2021-08-13", "2021-08-17", "2021-08-20", "2021-08-23", 
"2021-08-24", "2021-08-27", "2021-08-30", "2021-08-31", "2021-09-03", 
"2021-09-07", "2021-09-10", "2021-09-14", "2021-09-17", "2021-09-20", 
"2021-09-21", "2021-09-24", "2022-05-27", "2022-05-30", "2022-05-31", 
"2022-06-03", "2022-06-06", "2022-06-07", "2022-06-09", "2022-06-10", 
"2022-06-14", "2022-06-17", "2022-06-20", "2022-06-21", "2022-06-23", 
"2022-06-24", "2022-06-27", "2022-06-28", "2022-06-30", "2022-07-05", 
"2022-07-07", "2022-07-08", "2022-07-11", "2022-07-15", "2022-07-18", 
"2022-07-21", "2022-07-22", "2022-07-28", "2022-07-29", "2022-08-04", 
"2022-08-05", "2022-08-18", "2022-08-19", "2022-08-22", "2022-08-25", 
"2022-08-26"), class = "factor"), julian.coll = c(215, 222, 222, 
229, 141, 150, 161, 131, 161, 151, 158, 165, 253, 260, 267, 253, 
260, 267), year = c(2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2021L, 2022L, 2021L, 2022L, 2022L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L), tree.id = structure(c(7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 17L, 17L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L
), .Label = c("1", "100b", "100voc", "101", "101b", "102", "102b", 
"103", "103b", "104", "105", "105b", "106", "106b", "107", "107b", 
"108", "108bb", "109", "109b", "11", "111b", "112b", "113", "113b", 
"113voc", "114", "114b", "115", "116", "116b", "117", "117b", 
"118", "118b", "119", "119b", "11b", "11c", "12", "120", "120b", 
"121", "121b", "122", "122b", "123", "123b", "124", "124b", "125", 
"125b", "126", "126b", "127b", "128b", "128voc", "129b", "12b", 
"12c", "13", "130", "131b", "132b", "133b", "134", "134b", "134bb", 
"135", "138b", "139", "139b", "13b", "14", "142", "142b", "143", 
"143b", "14b", "15", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", "155", 
"157", "15b", "16", "160voc", "162b", "164", "165", "168", "168b", 
"169", "169b", "16b", "17", "170", "171", "172", "173", "174", 
"175", "177", "178", "179", "17b", "18", "180", "182", "183", 
"186", "187", "188", "189", "18b", "19", "190", "191", "192", 
"193", "194", "195", "196", "198", "19b", "2", "20", "201", "202", 
"204", "205", "206", "207", "209", "20b", "21", "210", "211", 
"22", "22b", "22bb", "23", "23b", "24", "24bb", "25", "25b", 
"26", "26bb", "26voc", "27", "27b", "28", "29b", "29voc", "30", 
"31", "31b", "32", "32b", "33", "33b", "34", "37", "37b", "38", 
"38b", "39", "39b", "40b", "41", "41b", "41voc", "42", "42b", 
"43", "43b", "44", "44b", "45", "45b", "46", "46b", "47", "48", 
"48b", "49", "49b", "5", "50", "50b", "51", "51b", "52", "52bb", 
"53", "53b", "54", "54b", "55b", "56b", "57b", "59", "59b", "5b", 
"60", "60b", "61", "62b", "63", "63b", "64", "64bb", "65", "65b", 
"65cb", "66b", "67bb", "68", "68b", "68voc", "69", "69b", "70", 
"70b", "70bb", "70c", "71c", "71d", "72", "72b", "73", "73bb", 
"74", "74b", "75", "75b", "76", "76b", "77", "77b", "78", "78b", 
"79", "79b", "7b", "80", "80b", "81b", "82", "82b", "85", "85b", 
"86b", "87b", "88", "88b", "89b", "91", "92", "92b", "93", "93b", 
"94", "95", "95b", "96", "97", "97b", "98b", "98e", "99voc", 
"9b", "v12", "v22", "v23", "v24", "v26", "v27"), class = "factor"), 
    week = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 0.43, 2, 0.43, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
    3, 1, 2, 3), month = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 
    5L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), pa = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    arthrop = c(0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), groups = structure(list(
    date = structure(c(4L, 9L, 13L, 44L, 47L, 47L, 49L, 58L, 
    58L, 60L, 60L, 63L, 63L, 65L, 69L, 71L, 71L, 72L), .Label = c("2021-05-03", 
    "2021-05-05", "2021-05-07", "2021-05-11", "2021-05-12", "2021-05-14", 
    "2021-05-17", "2021-05-19", "2021-05-21", "2021-05-25", "2021-05-26", 
    "2021-05-28", "2021-05-31", "2021-06-04", "2021-06-07", "2021-06-11", 
    "2021-06-14", "2021-06-15", "2021-06-16", "2021-06-18", "2021-06-20", 
    "2021-06-21", "2021-06-22", "2021-06-25", "2021-06-27", "2021-06-28", 
    "2021-06-29", "2021-07-02", "2021-07-03", "2021-07-05", "2021-07-06", 
    "2021-07-09", "2021-07-12", "2021-07-13", "2021-07-16", "2021-07-19", 
    "2021-07-20", "2021-07-23", "2021-07-25", "2021-07-26", "2021-07-27", 
    "2021-07-30", "2021-08-02", "2021-08-03", "2021-08-06", "2021-08-09", 
    "2021-08-10", "2021-08-13", "2021-08-17", "2021-08-20", "2021-08-23", 
    "2021-08-24", "2021-08-27", "2021-08-30", "2021-08-31", "2021-09-03", 
    "2021-09-07", "2021-09-10", "2021-09-14", "2021-09-17", "2021-09-20", 
    "2021-09-21", "2021-09-24", "2022-05-27", "2022-05-30", "2022-05-31", 
    "2022-06-03", "2022-06-06", "2022-06-07", "2022-06-09", "2022-06-10", 
    "2022-06-14", "2022-06-17", "2022-06-20", "2022-06-21", "2022-06-23", 
    "2022-06-24", "2022-06-27", "2022-06-28", "2022-06-30", "2022-07-05", 
    "2022-07-07", "2022-07-08", "2022-07-11", "2022-07-15", "2022-07-18", 
    "2022-07-21", "2022-07-22", "2022-07-28", "2022-07-29", "2022-08-04", 
    "2022-08-05", "2022-08-18", "2022-08-19", "2022-08-22", "2022-08-25", 
    "2022-08-26"), class = "factor"), julian.coll = c(131, 141, 
    151, 215, 222, 222, 229, 253, 253, 260, 260, 267, 267, 150, 
    158, 161, 161, 165), year = c(2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
    2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
    2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L), tree.id = structure(c(17L, 
    10L, 21L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 22L, 23L, 22L, 23L, 22L, 23L, 10L, 
    21L, 10L, 17L, 21L), .Label = c("1", "100b", "100voc", "101", 
    "101b", "102", "102b", "103", "103b", "104", "105", "105b", 
    "106", "106b", "107", "107b", "108", "108bb", "109", "109b", 
    "11", "111b", "112b", "113", "113b", "113voc", "114", "114b", 
    "115", "116", "116b", "117", "117b", "118", "118b", "119", 
    "119b", "11b", "11c", "12", "120", "120b", "121", "121b", 
    "122", "122b", "123", "123b", "124", "124b", "125", "125b", 
    "126", "126b", "127b", "128b", "128voc", "129b", "12b", "12c", 
    "13", "130", "131b", "132b", "133b", "134", "134b", "134bb", 
    "135", "138b", "139", "139b", "13b", "14", "142", "142b", 
    "143", "143b", "14b", "15", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", 
    "155", "157", "15b", "16", "160voc", "162b", "164", "165", 
    "168", "168b", "169", "169b", "16b", "17", "170", "171", 
    "172", "173", "174", "175", "177", "178", "179", "17b", "18", 
    "180", "182", "183", "186", "187", "188", "189", "18b", "19", 
    "190", "191", "192", "193", "194", "195", "196", "198", "19b", 
    "2", "20", "201", "202", "204", "205", "206", "207", "209", 
    "20b", "21", "210", "211", "22", "22b", "22bb", "23", "23b", 
    "24", "24bb", "25", "25b", "26", "26bb", "26voc", "27", "27b", 
    "28", "29b", "29voc", "30", "31", "31b", "32", "32b", "33", 
    "33b", "34", "37", "37b", "38", "38b", "39", "39b", "40b", 
    "41", "41b", "41voc", "42", "42b", "43", "43b", "44", "44b", 
    "45", "45b", "46", "46b", "47", "48", "48b", "49", "49b", 
    "5", "50", "50b", "51", "51b", "52", "52bb", "53", "53b", 
    "54", "54b", "55b", "56b", "57b", "59", "59b", "5b", "60", 
    "60b", "61", "62b", "63", "63b", "64", "64bb", "65", "65b", 
    "65cb", "66b", "67bb", "68", "68b", "68voc", "69", "69b", 
    "70", "70b", "70bb", "70c", "71c", "71d", "72", "72b", "73", 
    "73bb", "74", "74b", "75", "75b", "76", "76b", "77", "77b", 
    "78", "78b", "79", "79b", "7b", "80", "80b", "81b", "82", 
    "82b", "85", "85b", "86b", "87b", "88", "88b", "89b", "91", 
    "92", "92b", "93", "93b", "94", "95", "95b", "96", "97", 
    "97b", "98b", "98e", "99voc", "9b", "v12", "v22", "v23", 
    "v24", "v26", "v27"), class = "factor"), week = c(0.43, 1, 
    3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0.43, 1, 2, 1, 2), month = c(5L, 
    5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L), .rows = structure(list(8L, 5L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
        4L, 13L, 16L, 14L, 17L, 15L, 18L, 6L, 11L, 7L, 9L, 12L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 18L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to learn some code so I can remove observations of trees that are an earlier "week" value when "pa" is zero. Ultimately, I would like a dataset with what I call 'terminal observations'.

Example of what I hope to achieve using the above subset data:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(47L, 49L, 9L, 71L, 4L, 71L, 
13L, 72L, 63L, 63L), .Label = c("2021-05-03", "2021-05-05", "2021-05-07", 
"2021-05-11", "2021-05-12", "2021-05-14", "2021-05-17", "2021-05-19", 
"2021-05-21", "2021-05-25", "2021-05-26", "2021-05-28", "2021-05-31", 
"2021-06-04", "2021-06-07", "2021-06-11", "2021-06-14", "2021-06-15", 
"2021-06-16", "2021-06-18", "2021-06-20", "2021-06-21", "2021-06-22", 
"2021-06-25", "2021-06-27", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-29", "2021-07-02", 
"2021-07-03", "2021-07-05", "2021-07-06", "2021-07-09", "2021-07-12", 
"2021-07-13", "2021-07-16", "2021-07-19", "2021-07-20", "2021-07-23", 
"2021-07-25", "2021-07-26", "2021-07-27", "2021-07-30", "2021-08-02", 
"2021-08-03", "2021-08-06", "2021-08-09", "2021-08-10", "2021-08-13", 
"2021-08-17", "2021-08-20", "2021-08-23", "2021-08-24", "2021-08-27", 
"2021-08-30", "2021-08-31", "2021-09-03", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-10", 
"2021-09-14", "2021-09-17", "2021-09-20", "2021-09-21", "2021-09-24", 
"2022-05-27", "2022-05-30", "2022-05-31", "2022-06-03", "2022-06-06", 
"2022-06-07", "2022-06-09", "2022-06-10", "2022-06-14", "2022-06-17", 
"2022-06-20", "2022-06-21", "2022-06-23", "2022-06-24", "2022-06-27", 
"2022-06-28", "2022-06-30", "2022-07-05", "2022-07-07", "2022-07-08", 
"2022-07-11", "2022-07-15", "2022-07-18", "2022-07-21", "2022-07-22", 
"2022-07-28", "2022-07-29", "2022-08-04", "2022-08-05", "2022-08-18", 
"2022-08-19", "2022-08-22", "2022-08-25", "2022-08-26"), class = "factor"), 
    julian.coll = c(222, 229, 141, 161, 131, 161, 151, 165, 267, 
    267), year = c(2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2022L, 2021L, 2022L, 
    2021L, 2022L, 2021L, 2021L), tree.id = structure(c(7L, 9L, 
    10L, 10L, 17L, 17L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 23L), .Label = c("1", 
    "100b", "100voc", "101", "101b", "102", "102b", "103", "103b", 
    "104", "105", "105b", "106", "106b", "107", "107b", "108", 
    "108bb", "109", "109b", "11", "111b", "112b", "113", "113b", 
    "113voc", "114", "114b", "115", "116", "116b", "117", "117b", 
    "118", "118b", "119", "119b", "11b", "11c", "12", "120", 
    "120b", "121", "121b", "122", "122b", "123", "123b", "124", 
    "124b", "125", "125b", "126", "126b", "127b", "128b", "128voc", 
    "129b", "12b", "12c", "13", "130", "131b", "132b", "133b", 
    "134", "134b", "134bb", "135", "138b", "139", "139b", "13b", 
    "14", "142", "142b", "143", "143b", "14b", "15", "150", "151", 
    "152", "153", "154", "155", "157", "15b", "16", "160voc", 
    "162b", "164", "165", "168", "168b", "169", "169b", "16b", 
    "17", "170", "171", "172", "173", "174", "175", "177", "178", 
    "179", "17b", "18", "180", "182", "183", "186", "187", "188", 
    "189", "18b", "19", "190", "191", "192", "193", "194", "195", 
    "196", "198", "19b", "2", "20", "201", "202", "204", "205", 
    "206", "207", "209", "20b", "21", "210", "211", "22", "22b", 
    "22bb", "23", "23b", "24", "24bb", "25", "25b", "26", "26bb", 
    "26voc", "27", "27b", "28", "29b", "29voc", "30", "31", "31b", 
    "32", "32b", "33", "33b", "34", "37", "37b", "38", "38b", 
    "39", "39b", "40b", "41", "41b", "41voc", "42", "42b", "43", 
    "43b", "44", "44b", "45", "45b", "46", "46b", "47", "48", 
    "48b", "49", "49b", "5", "50", "50b", "51", "51b", "52", 
    "52bb", "53", "53b", "54", "54b", "55b", "56b", "57b", "59", 
    "59b", "5b", "60", "60b", "61", "62b", "63", "63b", "64", 
    "64bb", "65", "65b", "65cb", "66b", "67bb", "68", "68b", 
    "68voc", "69", "69b", "70", "70b", "70bb", "70c", "71c", 
    "71d", "72", "72b", "73", "73bb", "74", "74b", "75", "75b", 
    "76", "76b", "77", "77b", "78", "78b", "79", "79b", "7b", 
    "80", "80b", "81b", "82", "82b", "85", "85b", "86b", "87b", 
    "88", "88b", "89b", "91", "92", "92b", "93", "93b", "94", 
    "95", "95b", "96", "97", "97b", "98b", "98e", "99voc", "9b", 
    "v12", "v22", "v23", "v24", "v26", "v27"), class = "factor"), 
    week = c(2, 3, 1, 2, 0.43, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3), month = c(8L, 
    8L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 9L), pa = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), arthrop = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
    date = structure(c(4L, 9L, 13L, 47L, 49L, 63L, 63L, 71L, 
    71L, 72L), .Label = c("2021-05-03", "2021-05-05", "2021-05-07", 
    "2021-05-11", "2021-05-12", "2021-05-14", "2021-05-17", "2021-05-19", 
    "2021-05-21", "2021-05-25", "2021-05-26", "2021-05-28", "2021-05-31", 
    "2021-06-04", "2021-06-07", "2021-06-11", "2021-06-14", "2021-06-15", 
    "2021-06-16", "2021-06-18", "2021-06-20", "2021-06-21", "2021-06-22", 
    "2021-06-25", "2021-06-27", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-29", "2021-07-02", 
    "2021-07-03", "2021-07-05", "2021-07-06", "2021-07-09", "2021-07-12", 
    "2021-07-13", "2021-07-16", "2021-07-19", "2021-07-20", "2021-07-23", 
    "2021-07-25", "2021-07-26", "2021-07-27", "2021-07-30", "2021-08-02", 
    "2021-08-03", "2021-08-06", "2021-08-09", "2021-08-10", "2021-08-13", 
    "2021-08-17", "2021-08-20", "2021-08-23", "2021-08-24", "2021-08-27", 
    "2021-08-30", "2021-08-31", "2021-09-03", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-10", 
    "2021-09-14", "2021-09-17", "2021-09-20", "2021-09-21", "2021-09-24", 
    "2022-05-27", "2022-05-30", "2022-05-31", "2022-06-03", "2022-06-06", 
    "2022-06-07", "2022-06-09", "2022-06-10", "2022-06-14", "2022-06-17", 
    "2022-06-20", "2022-06-21", "2022-06-23", "2022-06-24", "2022-06-27", 
    "2022-06-28", "2022-06-30", "2022-07-05", "2022-07-07", "2022-07-08", 
    "2022-07-11", "2022-07-15", "2022-07-18", "2022-07-21", "2022-07-22", 
    "2022-07-28", "2022-07-29", "2022-08-04", "2022-08-05", "2022-08-18", 
    "2022-08-19", "2022-08-22", "2022-08-25", "2022-08-26"), class = "factor"), 
    julian.coll = c(131, 141, 151, 222, 229, 267, 267, 161, 161, 
    165), year = c(2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
    2021L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L), tree.id = structure(c(17L, 10L, 
    21L, 7L, 9L, 22L, 23L, 10L, 17L, 21L), .Label = c("1", "100b", 
    "100voc", "101", "101b", "102", "102b", "103", "103b", "104", 
    "105", "105b", "106", "106b", "107", "107b", "108", "108bb", 
    "109", "109b", "11", "111b", "112b", "113", "113b", "113voc", 
    "114", "114b", "115", "116", "116b", "117", "117b", "118", 
    "118b", "119", "119b", "11b", "11c", "12", "120", "120b", 
    "121", "121b", "122", "122b", "123", "123b", "124", "124b", 
    "125", "125b", "126", "126b", "127b", "128b", "128voc", "129b", 
    "12b", "12c", "13", "130", "131b", "132b", "133b", "134", 
    "134b", "134bb", "135", "138b", "139", "139b", "13b", "14", 
    "142", "142b", "143", "143b", "14b", "15", "150", "151", 
    "152", "153", "154", "155", "157", "15b", "16", "160voc", 
    "162b", "164", "165", "168", "168b", "169", "169b", "16b", 
    "17", "170", "171", "172", "173", "174", "175", "177", "178", 
    "179", "17b", "18", "180", "182", "183", "186", "187", "188", 
    "189", "18b", "19", "190", "191", "192", "193", "194", "195", 
    "196", "198", "19b", "2", "20", "201", "202", "204", "205", 
    "206", "207", "209", "20b", "21", "210", "211", "22", "22b", 
    "22bb", "23", "23b", "24", "24bb", "25", "25b", "26", "26bb", 
    "26voc", "27", "27b", "28", "29b", "29voc", "30", "31", "31b", 
    "32", "32b", "33", "33b", "34", "37", "37b", "38", "38b", 
    "39", "39b", "40b", "41", "41b", "41voc", "42", "42b", "43", 
    "43b", "44", "44b", "45", "45b", "46", "46b", "47", "48", 
    "48b", "49", "49b", "5", "50", "50b", "51", "51b", "52", 
    "52bb", "53", "53b", "54", "54b", "55b", "56b", "57b", "59", 
    "59b", "5b", "60", "60b", "61", "62b", "63", "63b", "64", 
    "64bb", "65", "65b", "65cb", "66b", "67bb", "68", "68b", 
    "68voc", "69", "69b", "70", "70b", "70bb", "70c", "71c", 
    "71d", "72", "72b", "73", "73bb", "74", "74b", "75", "75b", 
    "76", "76b", "77", "77b", "78", "78b", "79", "79b", "7b", 
    "80", "80b", "81b", "82", "82b", "85", "85b", "86b", "87b", 
    "88", "88b", "89b", "91", "92", "92b", "93", "93b", "94", 
    "95", "95b", "96", "97", "97b", "98b", "98e", "99voc", "9b", 
    "v12", "v22", "v23", "v24", "v26", "v27"), class = "factor"), 
    week = c(0.43, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2), month = c(5L, 
    5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .rows = structure(list(
        5L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 4L, 6L, 8L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064). You should probably be suing the `ifelse()` inside a `mutate()` if you want the `group_by` to work.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you and sorry for my slow response, I have edited my original question. I will try mutate with an ifelse and group_by, but I still may need some help.

Answer (score -1):

The pipe operator, unless specified otherwise, pass the argument (normally a dataframe) to the first argument of the function in the left hand side. Thus you're doing:

```
ifelse(terminal.obs.fr, ifelse(group_by(year, tree.id)%>%tally() >1, "T", "F")
```

But that's not what you want. `ifelse()` shouldn't receive a dataframe as its first argument, and `group_by()` isn't receiving the dataframe it needs. So, you need to specify that you don't want the default behaviour of the pipe.

You can do that by placing a `.` where you want the right hand side to go. Furthermore, if you need to pass that `.` into a function (not directly to an argument of the function in the l.h.s.), you need to encapsule the whole expression in curly braces:

```
terminal.obs.fr %>% {ifelse(group_by(., year, tree.id) %>% tally() > 1, "T", "F")}
```

This doesn't mean that you *should* be doing this, there are probably more natural ways to accomplish what you want.

Comment: `df %>% group_by(tree.id, year) %>% top_n(1, week) -> new_df` This seemed to work for me, it  did exactly what I needed. I have a few things to clean up still.